# Why my connect4 minimax doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax

Can you please explain to me why my AI can play properly, until player has 3 in a row in sixth or seventh column then my AI refuses to block him. And another problem is in a position when my AI can win in 1 move, but he will rather choose a longer game. Can anyone help me please.

Returns a value for a winning move

```
def utility(board):
    if terminal(board):
        if winning_move(board, X):
            return 1000000
        elif winning_move(board, O):
            return -10000
        else:
            return 0
```

Calculates the score of position when depth = 0

```
def compute_score(block, board, col, row):
    score = 0

    if block.count(X) == 4 and block.count("-") == 0:
        score += 100000
    elif block.count(X) == 3 and block.count("-") == 1:
        score += 10
    elif block.count(X) == 2 and block.count("-") == 2:
        score += 3

    if block.count(O) == 4 and block.count("-") == 0:
        score -= 1000000
    elif block.count(O) == 3 and block.count("-") == 1:
        score -= 6
    elif block.count(O) == 2 and block.count("-") == 2:
        score -= 2
    return score
```

Gives value to every possible "four block"

```
def score_position(board):
    score = 0
    mid_section = []

#increases score because playing in middle is usually good move
    for col in range(5):
        mid_section.append(board[col][x // 2])
    score += mid_section.count(X) * 3

#claculates score of all horizontal 4 in a rows
    for row in range(y):
        for col in range(x - 3):
            block = board[col: col + 4]
            score += compute_score(block, board, col, row)

#claculates score of all vertical 4 in a rows
    for col in range(x):
        for row in range(y - 3):
            block = [board[row][col], board[row + 1][col], board[row + 2][col], board[row + 3][col]]
            score += compute_score(block, board, col, row)


#claculates score of all diagonals from left bottom to right top 4 in a rows
    for row in range(y - 3):
        for col in range(x - 3):
            block = [board[row][col], board[row + 1][col + 1], board[row + 2][col + 2], board[row + 3][col + 3]]
            score += compute_score(block, board, col, row)

#claculates score of all diagonals from right bottom to left top 4 in a rows
    for row in range(y - 3):
        for col in range(x - 1, 2, -1):
            block = [board[row][col], board[row + 1][col - 1], board[row + 2][col - 2], board[row + 3][col - 3]]
            score += compute_score(block, board, col, row)
    return score
```

The minimax algorithm  (if you want to know more about this algorithm check this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-hh51ncgDI)

```
def minimax(board, depth):
    #if terminal(board):
     #   return None

    best_move = None
    alpha = -math.inf
    beta = math.inf

    if player(board) == X:
        if board == initial_state():
            best_move = x//2
            return best_move

        best_score = -math.inf
        for action in actions(board):
            score = minimaze(result(board, action), alpha, beta, depth)
            alpha = max(alpha, score)
            if score > best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_move = action
        return best_move

    else:
        best_score = math.inf
        for action in actions(board):
            score = maximaze(result(board, action), alpha, beta, depth)
            beta = min(beta, score)
            if score < best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_move = action
        print(best_move)
        return best_move
```

The minimazing player (returns the best player move four the specific position)

```
def minimaze(board, alpha, beta, depth):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    elif depth <= 0:
        return score_position(board)

    v = math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = min(v, maximaze(result(board, action), alpha, beta, depth - 1))
        beta = min(beta, v)
    return v
```

The maximazing AI (returns the best AI move four the specific position)

```
def maximaze(board, alpha, beta, depth):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    elif depth <= 0:
        return score_position(board)

    v = -math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = max(v, minimaze(result(board, action), alpha, beta, depth - 1))
        alpha = max(alpha, v)
    return v
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on the exact same project recently :)
For your second problem, to make the AI win as fast as it can you should change your score system.

- When the game hasn't over, You can use your `score_position` function.
- When the game is over (some player had won the game), Give score based on how many turns passed in the game. But also indicate that the game had over.
  You can do that by changing the score addition when there are four pieces in a row:

```py
if block.count(X) == 4 and block.count("-") == 0:
    score += 100000 * (places_in_board - turns_played + 1)

if block.count(O) == 4 and block.count("-") == 0:
    score -= 1000000 * (places_in_board - turns_played + 1)
```

Where `places_in_board` is the number of places of your board and `turns_played` is the number of turns that had passed in the game.

Notice that as you win the game in less turns, the score you get is higher.
This way the AI would 'prefer' to take the short way to a win- The score it would get just will be greater.

AND, as a side effect you get another improvement to your AI!! 
If the AI got somehow into a situation which it will *always* lose at (if the opponent plays perfectly), It would prefer to take the **longest** way to its lost. Why? Because in the 'longest lose' `turns_played` will be greater, so

```py
score -= 1000000 * (places_in_board - turns_left + 1)
```

will reduce less to the score. The score would be higher so the AI would prefer to take that 'long lose'.

Here is link for my connect4 AI if you need some reference: https://github.com/YotamZaiger1/connect_4_AI
My scoring function is in `Board` file, called "state_value".

Hope I helped, good luck!

Comment: Thank you this really helps! But I still have a problem that I can not understand. The AI can easily beat me. But if I have a winning move in 5th, 6th or 7th column in refuses to block me or if he has a winning move in one of this columns then he refuses to win.

Comment: Your `minimax` function looks fine. I think the problem might be in the `score_position` function. Can you give some explanation about this function? Like what is the idea of the score calculation.

Comment: This function should return a score of a position. It gives all 4 in a rows to a compute_score function where it calculates the score. (+ I added some comments in the code)

Comment: I assume your `board` variable is some sort of 2 dimensioal list. Notice that in your `score_position` function, when you calculates the 'score of all horizontal 4 in a rows', you use `block = board[col: col + 4]`. Then, `block` will be also a 2 dimensioal list and not a regular list as in the other calculations. Maybe that what causing the problem?

Comment: Oh, yeah I didn't see that thanks for finding it I fixed it but. The main problem is still there, to better understand my problem here is what my AI does: AI starts at 4 I play 6 AI plays 4 I play 6 AI plays 3 I play 6 AI plays 2 and I win by playing 6 again but if I play the same thing on the other side (6 => 2) so AI starts at 4 I play 2 AI plays 4 I play 2 and for some reason there is a difference in AI because he plays 4 not 3(4 is a better move) so if I play 2 again AI wins. So if I play on the left side AI plays optimally but if I play on the right side it plays like a toddler.